# Python: converting gzip file to an ordinary file

Tags: python, gzip, biopython

I have an **ent** file, compressed to **.gz**. I need to read it and put into Biopython parser. The problem is that the parser takes either file path or file object, but I get gzip file instead. Now I convert it like this:

```
file_path = 'file.ent.gz' # path to current file

file = gzip.open(file_path, 'rb') 
content = file.read() # its content

write_path = 'temp.ent' # let's write it back but as ordinary file
write_file = open(write_path, 'w')
write_file.write(content)
write_file.close()

third_file = open(write_path, 'r') #open this ordinary noncompressed file

structure = parser.get_structure('', third_file) #and finally put it into the parser
```

As you can see, this solution is ugly af but most importantly it takes loads of time because it writes to a drive and reads it twice, which is a problem as long as I have to do millions of such operations.

Googling didn't help me at all, docs didn't too. Is it possible to make the convertion faster?

Comment: `gzip.open` does return a file object, doesn't it? At least the documentation explicitly says so: https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to convert anything, just feed your parser with the stream returned by `gzip.open()`:

```
file_path = 'file.ent.gz' # path to current file
with gzip.open(file_path, 'rb') as finput:
    structure = parser.get_structure('', finput)
```

Reason: `open()` returns a file stream of the file content. `gzip.open()` returns a file stream of the uncompressed file content. Which is exactly what you need. This is a good example of the old saying:

> if it looks like a duck and walks like a duck, it is a duck

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Type(finput) in your case returns **<class 'gzip.GzipFile'>**, but parser.get_structure, as documentation says, needs *file - name of the PDB file OR an open filehandle*

EDITED: oh, it really works, thank you!

Comment: You parser should not rely on the type of object that is passed to it, but on only the presence of a `.read()` method to get the stream content. EDITED: and fortunately it looks like it is really what it does :)